# C# Linq to Entities - Method for determining whether an underlying data source is readonly

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq-to-entities

Is there a better approach than trying to write and just catching the exception?

We have various versions of the same database and today I'm working against a readonly version, this is fine for 99% of my tasks but the application sometimes saves its state back to the DB and I'd like to be able to try this iff the underlying SQL Server instance is writable.

Comment: You should probably have your application coded for this anyway, so that it can deal with multiple roles and access privileges.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run a query against the server checking what permissions your user login has for that database. There is a built-in Transact-SQL function to do this named `HAS_PERMS_BY_NAME` [(Link to MSDN)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189802.aspx).

Example query to check if you have `INSERT` permissions.

```
SELECT HAS_PERMS_BY_NAME('database', 'OBJECT', 'INSERT');
```

Also have a look at `FN_BUILTIN_PERMISSIONS` [(Link to MSDN)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186234.aspx). This MSDN page has listings of the possible values that you can use in `HAS_PERMS_BY_NAME`.

HTH,